# Positive feedback in Op-Amp Oscillators

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, feedback, positive-feedback

Is positive feedback necessary in op-amp oscillators? Can you make one using negative feedback?

Comment: Have you studied any basic theory about oscillator circuits? To understand how they work etc. If not, this might be a good start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVS8Puf4tiw

Answer (score 6):

The oscillation condition formulated by H. Barkhausen requires a loop gain of unity (or slightly larger for a safe start of oscillation) for the desired oscillation frequency fo only. Therefore, the feedback circuitry must be frequency-dependent.

That means: The magnitude for the loop gain must be |Aloop|=1 with a zero phase shift for the frequency fo only.

This is identical to **positive feedback** for the **desired frequency fo** only. For all other frequencies this condition must not be fulfilled - in particular, we require **negative feedback for DC** (for a stable DC operating point).

Added: For the frequency-selective feedback circuitry you can use any phase-sensitive filter which allows a phase shift of zero deg or -180deg at the frequency fo (lowpass, highpass, bandpass, band-stop, allpass).

Added: When the passive - frequency-selective - feedback circuit causes a -180deg phase shift (lowpass, highpass), the gain stage must be inverting; for 0deg phase shift (bandpass) it must be non-inverting.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is positive feedback necessary in op-amp oscillators?*

It's necessary in any oscillator.

> *Can you make one using negative feedback?*

If your oscillator is intended to produce a sinewave (for instance) then, almost certainly, to obtain a high-quality sinewave, you will also need to use negative feedback to control amplitude and distortion artefacts.

Comment: But why is it necessary?

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site AND you asked **your** question. What you are asking now (in a comment) is a whole different thing requiring the equivalent of several book pages to be written. That's beyond the scope of this website AND, it's likely you'll have a ton of follow up questions AND this **isn't how this site works** so, I suggest you do some background research work to understand why oscillators need feedback @JirhsKumar - neither should you edit your question once answers have arrived because that is seen as rude and moving the goalposts.

Answer (score 0):

It is the positive feedback that helps drive an op-amp into saturation (either the supply voltage +Vcc or -Vcc). Depending on whether the voltages at the inverting or the non-inverting terminal is greater, the output periodically shifts between the two supply voltages (+/- Vcc).
Some of the op-amp configurations that use positive as well as negative feedbacks are the "Astable" and the "Monostable" Multivibrator.

As LvW stated, all these are true only when the loop-gain of the op-amp configuration is greater than 1.

Comment: The above considerations are true for positive feedback with a loopgain>1 only.

Comment: @LvW Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's **not** a requirement for all types of oscillators to have feedback. But "generally", oscillators need positive feedback to start oscillating.

For the ones with positive feedback, the idea is to feed a portion of the output signal to the input **in phase** so that the input signal effectively increases. Think of an opamp: It just amplifies the the voltage difference of its inputs i.e. \$A_{OL}\cdot (V_+\ - V_-)\$. If you bring a portion of the output to the non-inverting input, you just basically increase the differential voltage. With this, you can get a gain higher than the open-loop gain! If the amount of positive feedback is large enough, the amplifier does not need any signal to generate an output because it starts to produce its own signal thanks to the positive feedback.

There are some requirements of course:

- **The oscillation should be at a certain frequency.** So the positive feedback network should be "highly selective" (i.e. narrow band or in other words, high Q) so that a certain frequency (or a very narrow frequency band) is fed back to the input in phase. This is done by basically placing a filter to the positive feedback path.
- **The amplitude should be constant.** This is where the negative feedback is needed. The loop gain should be 1 to keep the amplitude constant. This means that, if the attenuation at positive feedback network is 1/50 then the amplification at negative feedback network should be 50 i.e. 50 x 1/50 = 1. If the loop gain is less than 1 then the output will be oscillating but the amplitude will be decaying. So a negative feedback is really needed.

Comment: You mention that the "overall closed-loop gain should be 1".  This is not correct. Instead, the LOOP GAIN is required to be unity for the desired frequency. The closed loop has no input - hence, we cannot determine any "closed-loop gain". In contrary - when we use a grounded node for applying an input signal the closed-loop gain will be (theoretically) infinite.

Comment: @LvW You're right. Wrong term usage. Thanks. Fixing...

Comment: @R. Kilic May I ask you for an example for an oscillator without the reqirement of positive feedback (ref. to the 1st sentence of your contribution)? Thank you.

Comment: @LvW holy sh** what the hell was I thinking (sigh). I was trying to say "without feedback". Thanks for pointing out. Fixing...

Comment: Mmmhh.....oscillations without feedback? I never have seen such a circuitry (and I cannot see how this could work). The only exception from the loop gains unity gain rule is a circuit with a loop gain <1 which has a "digital" feedback which periodically gives a "bump" intothe loop.

Comment: @LvW UJT-based relaxation oscillators do not require feedback.

Comment: OK - agreed. On the other hand: To me, the term "oscillator" should be used for "linear" quasi-sinusoidal circuits only (not for relaxation types). But I must admit that this is a pure personal attitude and - most probably - not commonly agreed.